# SQL / PostgreSQL How to do a query that merge values from some columns into one row

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a table:

| [region] | [country] | [month] | [VAL] | [VAL_PY] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EU | Poland | January | x | a |
| EU | Poland | January | x1 | a2 |
| EU | Poland | February | xx | aa |
| EU | France | January | y | b |
| NA | Brazil | February | z | c |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

there is a need to make another table based on the one above, such as the one below,
one row for one country, 12 new columns = 12 months, the value in each country/month is the KPI:

| [region] | [country] | [January] | February] | ... | [December] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EU | Poland | KPI | KPI | ... | KPI |
| EU | France | KPI | KPI | ... | KPI |
| ... | ... | KPI | KPI | ... | KPI |

The KPI code:

```
CASE WHEN  sum(A."value_py")=0 THEN 0 
else round(((sum("value")-sum("value_py"))/sum("value"))*100,1 
END
```

Please help me, I can find the solution where there are duplicates in every country which is not acceptable

Comment: How many months do you need to push out columnwise?

Comment: all, 12 months.

Comment: the KPI should be calculated for every month separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pivoting the data. You can use `FILTER` to retrieve data for each specific column.

For example:

```
select
  region,
  country,
  case when sum(a.val_py) filter(where month = 'January') = 0 then 0 
       else round(((sum(val) filter(where month = 'January') - 
            sum(val_py) filter(where month = 'January')) / 
            sum(val_py) filter(where month = 'January')) * 100, 1) 
  end as january,
  case when sum(a.val_py) filter(where month = 'February') = 0 then 0 
       else round(((sum(val) filter(where month = 'February') - 
            sum(val_py) filter(where month = 'February')) / 
            sum(val_py) filter(where month = 'February')) * 100, 1) 
  end as february,
  -- add the rest of the months here...
from t
group by region, country
```

Comment: @Piotr It was a typo. It should say `GROUP BY`. Fixed.